# How to fill a plot region with tilted lines without using HatchFilling?

Tags: plotting, filling

I want to fill the region below the horizontal line at `50.9` with tilted lines. For recent versions of Mathematica, this can be done using `HatchFilling[]`. I am using `v11` that does not support it.

**Question**

What can be done to fill the indicated region using tilted lines but without using `HatchFilling[]`?

---

Here is my code for the plot:

```
Subscript[θ,23][δ_, θ12_, θ13_, α_, β_] := -(180/(2 π)) ArcTan[(Cos[(2 (α + β + δ) ) Degree] Sin[2 θ12 Degree] Cos[θ13 Degree] )/(Cos[(2 (α + β) + δ) Degree] Cos[θ12 Degree]^2 Sin[2 θ13 Degree])];
Tab1 = Table[{δ,Subscript[θ, 23][δ, Random[Real, {31.61 , 36.27 }], 
         Random[Real, {8.22 , 8.99 }], Random[Real, {-6 , 6 }],Random[Real, {-45, -20 }]]}, {δ , 0 , 360, 1 Degree}];
     Tab2 =DeleteCases[Tab1, {_?(0 < # < 20 || 31 < # < 45 || 55 < # < 128 || 135 < # < 148 || 152 < # < 225 || 231 < # < 300 || 315 < # < 331 || 342 < # < 360 &), _}];
    P1 = ListPlot[ Tab2, Frame -> { True, True, True, True}, PlotRange -> {40, 55}, FrameLabel -> {δ, Subscript[θ, 23]}, FrameStyle -> Thick, PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 5}, 
      BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 14}, GridLines -> {{}, {50.9}}, GridLinesStyle -> Darker[Gray, .8],Method -> {"GridLinesInFront" -> True}]
```

Comment: Instead of using the deprecated `Random[Real, ...` construct, you can explore and use the `RandomReal` function. There are other related functions such as `RandomInteger`, `RandomChoice`, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**With HatchFilling[]**

```
P0 = Plot[50.9, {x, 0, 400}, PlotStyle -> None, Filling -> Bottom, 
  FillingStyle -> Directive[Darker@Green, HatchFilling[]]
  ]

P1 = ListPlot[Tab2
  , Frame -> {True, True, True, True}
  , PlotRange -> {40, 55}
  , FrameLabel -> {δ, Subscript[θ, 23]}
  , FrameStyle -> Thick
  , PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 5}
  , BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 14}
  , GridLines -> {{}, {50.9}}
  , GridLinesStyle -> Darker[Gray, .8]
  , Method -> {"GridLinesInFront" -> True}
  , PlotRangePadding -> None
  ]

Show[P1, P0]
```

[image]

---

**Without HatchFilling[]**

Draw lines at an angle of choice before the plot using `Prolog`.

```
g = ListPlot[Tab2
  , Frame -> {True, True, True, True}
  , PlotRange -> {40, 55}
  , FrameLabel -> {\[Delta], Subscript[\[Theta], 23]}
  , FrameStyle -> Thick
  , PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 5}
  , BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 14}
  , GridLines -> {{}, {50.9}}
  , GridLinesStyle -> Darker[Gray, .8]
  , Method -> {"GridLinesInFront" -> True}
  , PlotRangePadding -> None
  , Prolog -> {
    Blue, Thin, Opacity[0.1]
    , Table[Line[{{a, 0}, {300 + a, 50.9}}], {a, -300, 400, 5}]
    }
  ]
```

[image]

Comment: Why HatchFilling is not working in my case? I think because mine is mathematica 11. Is it so?

Comment: Is there any other way to do the same thing without using Hatchfilling?

Comment: @SangeetaDey I have updated the answer. `HatchFilling[]` was introduced on `{2020, 3, 18}` whereas Mathematica 11 was introduced around August 2016.

Comment: Thank you so much. I am really grateful.

Comment: You are most welcome. Thanks for the accept.